# Stress Testing - EntityFramework issue - DBContext Creation

Tags: entity-framework-6, race-condition, stress-testing

I am doing stress testing for web api (webapi2) with 20 users on boarding in 0 seconds. I am getting the following errors.

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation. The connection is closed.
```

Another error

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting.
```

My code to get the DBContext, each time a new DBContext is getting created:

```
public static ForcesChecker_Context GetDataContext()
    {           
        return new ForcesChecker_Context();            
    }
```

For one web api request this code is getting executed multiple times and multiple instances of this object is getting created. When I call 20 users at a time, it generates 20* ~10 = ~200 objects are created.

My connection string:

```
Min Pool Size=1;Max Pool Size=200;
```

It seems there is a race condition.

What settings would help to allow more users to access my system concurrently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The reason was, **Connection Leak**. There are other places in the application wherein the DBContext object wasn't disposed properly. Particularly in UnitOfWork class, DBContext object is used, but not disposed inside the Dispose() method. That led to the connection leak. Subsequently, that led to the race condition when new threads (http requests) try to use a connection from the connection pool. Here is the solution code.

```
public class UnitOfWork: IDisposable, IUnitOfWork
{
    ForcesChecker_Context forcesContext; //EntityFramework DBContext
    ...
    public void Dispose()
    {
          forcesContext.Dispose(); //Leak prevented by this new line.
    }
    ...
}
```

Thumb rule is, always remember to use Transient Life Time for the DBContext. That is a new instance every time, and dispose them immediately after use.